# Render form from view in a template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-forms

I'm evaluating backbone.js, backbone-forms and Rails, and I have some problems ...

I have a view where I create a new model and a form, and I want to display this form with other html elements, so I'm using a template.

```
expedients_new.js.coffee
------------------------

class Globalbackbone.Views.ExpedientsNew extends Backbone.View

template: JST['expedients/new']

render: ->

@form = new Backbone.Form({
    model: @model
}).render();

console.log(@model.procedencia) 
console.log(@form) 
$(@el).html(@template(expedient: @model, form: @form ))
this
```

This view uses a template, and in this template, I want to render the form there, but I don't know how to do it ...

```
new.jst.eco
-----------

<h1>BackBones with GlobalWeb</h1>

<h2>Adding New Expedient</h2>

<%=@expedient.date%>
<hr>
<%=@form.el%>
<hr>
<%=@form%>
```

Thanks in advance,

regards

### EDIT

The current browser output where I expect the form is:
    [object HTMLFormElement]

Comment: Are you using some library on top of Backbone.js? because there is no Backbone.Form in Backbone.js. Aside from that you probably need to call `toJSON()` on your model when passing it to your template, and perhaps you need to do so for your form as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm using backbone-forms, it's in the question but maybe it's not well explained... The problem (not yet) is not toJSON, as I currently don't see the form in the browser, just [object HTMLFormElement]. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [usage instructions](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#usage) indicate that `@form` will be a Backbone view:

```
var form = new Backbone.Form({
    model: user
}).render();
```

and that means that `@form.el` will be a DOM element that you need to insert into the DOM:

```
$('body').append(form.el);
```

And if you look at [the source](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms/blob/master/src/form.js#L8), you'll see that `Backbone.Form` is a `Backbone.View` subclass:

```
var Form = (function() {
  return Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
```

Your code is trying to treat `@form` as though it was a string containing HTML:

```
<%=@form%>
```

so you end up with standard stringified version of a DOM element: `[object HTMLFormElement]`.

I think you'll have better luck if you have something like this in your view:

```
@$el.append(@template(expedient: @model))
@$el.append(@form.el)
```

and in your template:

```
<h1>BackBones with GlobalWeb</h1>

<h2>Adding New Expedient</h2>

<%=@expedient.date%>
<hr>
```

Then your form should appear after the `<hr>`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Now it works but I've changed this line    @$el.append(@form) into this one: @$el.append(@form.el) (added .el) What happens if I want to put the form in some specific place? Your method add it at the end, I tried something like this but it's not working as: $('#form_here').html(@form.el), as I have to replace it the div content in the @el Also, my model attributes are not parsed in the current form, I'll have to investigate this also. Thanks again!

Comment: @mongeta: Right, that should have been `.append(@form.el)`, sorry about that. You'd want something like `this.$('#form_here').html(@form.el)`, the `this.$()` is a shortcut for `this.$el.find()`, `this.$el` won't be in the DOM yet so just `$('#form_here')` won't find anything.